# How to implement an rss feed to a rails application using feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedjira

I want to firstly apologize for asking a very similar question to ones that already exist.  However, I couldn't quite find the thread and answers I was looking for.

Everywhere I research about implementing an rss feed to a rails application it's in the context of doing the implementation for a blog.  I would greatly appreciate any help in learning how to do this outside of this context.  I have some ruby experience (mainly writing rspec based test cases) but I have little to no experience using rails and even less web development experience in general.

I would just like to implement the feed on the index page of my rails app.  If anyone decides to tackle this question I would appreciate a very step by step tutorial...very granular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the simple-rss and open-uri gems.  I created a helper method in my pages controller:

```
def feed
  require 'simple-rss'
  require 'open-uri'

  @rss = SimpleRSS.parse open('http://url_goes_here')
  @rss = @rss.items
end
```

That's the base method.  I would recommend windows users of rails to really give simple-rss a shot.  I was trying to get the feedjira gem to install and never had any luck.